# Searching for childNodes returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I have this in my html page:

```
<nav>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</nav>
```

but when I run `var menuitem = document.getElementsByTagName('nav').childNodes;`
it returns "undefined".

Here is the entire javascript file with the relevant part at the end: http://pastebin.com/bVj2Ug4e

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a **`NodeList`** not a single element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList

Comment: Additionally, and that's the whole point, your DOM is not yet loaded when you execute this code.

Comment: @SnippetSpace Yes, even if there's only one. Not doing so would be far too inconsistent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this may work for you

```
var menuitem = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].childNodes;
```

as document.getElementsByTagName('nav') will return nodeList, and make sure you are running javascript after the dom ready.

Comment: So what does the [0] do? select the first one in the dom tree?

Comment: @SnippetSpace: It selects the first element of the `NodeList`. The order of the elements is the order in which they appear in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `.childNodes` on a **NodeList.**

NodeList Works Similar to Array But Not an array datatype in JavaScript.

In your Case, `document.getElementsByTagName('nav')` is returning a NodeList.

So you will have to select First Element of Array and then add "`.childNodes`" after it:

```
let menuitem = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')[0].childNodes;
```

You can also Use "`document.getElementByTagName()`" Method Instead of "`document.getElementsByTagName()`" if you don't need a Nodelist and Just a Single Node. In that case you will not need to select first element of node list. You can do this in following way:

```
let menuitem = document.getElementByTagName('nav').childNodes;
```